# Send integer data by swagger/postman in rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, postman, swagger-ui

I am submitting a form by swagger ui(as well as from postman)

`param :form, 'user[role]', :string, :required` . In the `user` model role is a enum containing the values like `enum role: [1,2,3]` . So In the paramters , I am sending 1 in the form field , but I am receiving like `{"user" => {"role" => "1"}}` which is correct. But the user form is giving `error role '1' is not a valid type`

```
Ruby 2.4
Rails 5.1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use enum when you are passing an array?. I use enums with a hash like this:

```
enum role: {
   customer: 1,
   seller: 2,
   "6.5": 2,
   "5.5": 0
}
```

And then you pass at the params

```
{"user" => {"role" => "admin"}}
```

Which save 0 at the instance for this case

Comment: enum automatically gets converted to hash

Comment: as per my requirement, I want to save integer values in the db

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma this will save integer values in the db as at my example this will save 0 as integer

Comment: correct, but when u submit the form from postman/swagger , it convert the value to string like '1' in my case , then enum dont find this string because it needs only integer

Comment: you can pass string as parameter at my example too `"role" => "admin"`

Comment: No, I want enum like { 0: 1, 1: 2}

Comment: above role is just an example , I have some other cases where I want to save integer values

Comment: then instead of admin pass, the value that you want(1, one, number, 33), at you still will save 0 at the database

Comment: this is my enum : {5.5=>0, 6=>1, 6.5=>2, 7=>3, 7.5=>4, 8=>5, 8.5=>6, 9=>7, 9.5=>8, 10=>9}

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma I edited my answer adding some examples for your case

Comment: in it , you pass "6.5" as string but my requrirement is float/integer

Comment: and I want to hit the request by swagger/postman, if i post the request by ajax it works